# Is it possible get the event user's rolling UIDatePicker items?

Tags: iphone

I hope to get the event when user is rolling UIDatePicker items.
Is it possible?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Comment: I m not sure about it. but i couldn't find any methods that you can use to implement this functionality. may be others can help you. You can ask Dave Delong for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [UIDatePicker Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html)

> When properly configured, a
>   UIDatePicker object sends an action
>   message when a user finishes rotating
>   one of the wheels to change the date
>   or time; the associated control event
>   is UIControlEventValueChanged. A
>   UIDatePicker object presents the
>   countdown timer but does not implement
>   it; the application must set up an
>   NSTimer object and update the seconds
>   as they’re counted down.

Code:

```
 [myDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: You can also implement a method like -(IBAction) datePickerValueChanged:(id)sender and wire things up with Interface Builder.